# I am 15 and 163 cm tall - will I grow taller?

Tags: nutrition, diet, exercise, height

I am a 15 year old Indian. I currently stand at 163 cms but I weigh 75 kg, which is overweight I know.
But is there any way I'll grow more? If yes, how much?

My dad's height is 172 cm and my mom is 157.

I've been measuring my height for some time now and I've grown about 5 cms in the last 6-7 months. However, I haven't had a huge growth spurt yet. But one of my grandads is just about 148 cms, I guess. So will I grow taller?

I don't think that this question is a duplicate. Here, I just asked if I could grow taller. But that is a purely scientific question, I believe.

Diet: I eat a mainly vegetarian diet with some chicken at least 2 days a week. I drink a glass of milk about 3 days a week. But I don't eat any other meat than chicken. I also eat some fruits 3 days in a week. However, I'm willing to change my diet if that would help me grow.

Exercise: I usually play sports. But these days I haven't been able to, because of my school work. But I have been thinking of working out to reduce fat.

Comment: Plus: It is a personal medical question.

Comment: This is more of a health advice kind of question. I am migrating this to [health.se] but you **should** add more details. How tall you may grow depends on a lot of factors such as diet, physical exercise etc. So I guess this may also be considered broad. I won't be surprised if they close it.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to tell if you are going to grow taller or not is to have an x-ray done of [the epiphyseal plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphyseal_plate). These are segments at each end of the long bones in your body where bone growth (and thus height increase) occur. They are cartilaginous plates that gradually increase the length of the bone by laying down new matrix. When they are fully closed and turned to bone themselves, growth has stopped.

If the plates are not yet closed, then yes, you will probably grow some more. How much, that's not something that can really be determined. They can make predictions based on the xrays, but that is not a guarantee. If they are closed, then no, you won't grow any taller.

Height is genetically determined, your body knows at birth how tall it's going to be. The only things that will affect this are hormone/growth disorders (Such as hypo or hyperpituitarism for example), or other environmental factors such as chronic malnutrition.